# Creating fancy info windows on google maps using the javascript api that looks like the google maps original

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have been trying to create fancy info windows like google maps have on their maps. 
what makes it fancy? 
1. the tip of the info window is long and narrow and looks slick coming out of the marker
2. there is a shadow with the shape of the info window on the google map itself.

In the documentation of the maps api there is the official info window:

> https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

but I also found this one from the utility library:

> http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html

which I use like so:

```
var infoWindowHTML = get_movingInfoWindowHTML();
    context.bubble = new InfoBubble({
        content: infoWindowHTML,
        padding:5,
        borderColor: "#ccc",
        ShadowStyle:1,
        hideCloseButton:true,
        arrowSize:25,
        arrowStyle:1,
        arrowPosition:99,
        borderRadius:0,
        width:150,
        height:150
    });
    context.bubble.open(map,marker);
```

even though in the example of info bubble they show it with a shadow, currently the shadow is not working for me with this code.

but the bigger problem is that bubble info doesn't look as slick and fancy as the one google maps are using, the arrow is thick and not slick.

How can I get to a result like the one on google maps? 
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try using infoBox. These are as functional as infowindows and are much more customizable.
[infoBox reference](https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html)